# Error : java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

I am getting this exception when  adding the product in a cart or removing the product from cart.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:454) at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510)
>   at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.Cart.toString(Cart.java:82) at
>   java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994) at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131) at
>   com.sbk.shoppingbackend.dto.User.toString(User.java:182) at

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is only stack dump.

Comment: You posted a very long exception and no code. This makes it extreely difficult for you to get help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`User.toString` is invoking `Cart.toString` then
`Cart.toString` is invoking `User.toString` and again and again.

To solve this you should change one of this method.

Comment: ok i just removed toString method from cart Controller it is working fine thanks